# Spring Java Email exception

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm trying to implement my application so that when a user hits the send button an email is generated automatically and sent to another recipient. I research this on the Spring docs and found a way to try it. But so far an exception keeps coming up:

```
  ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/MailException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853)
at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. 

 determine CandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:976)
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)at 
                                                                                        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at 
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at 
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
at 

   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mail.MailException
at 

  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at 

  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 32 more
```

For the implementation I modified an example on the spring website and added it to my constructor method for submitting the form:

```
   public class ModuleController {

private MailSender mailSender;
   private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

   public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
  }

  public void setTemplateMessage(SimpleMailMessage templateMessage) {
    this.templateMessage = templateMessage;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/module", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "send")
public String sendModule(@ModelAttribute("module") Module module,BindingResult   
  result, ModelMap map) {
 SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.templateMessage);

    msg.setTo(module.getSta().getEmail());

    msg.setText(
     "Dear " + module.getSta().getName()
         + "a coursework has been submitted for checking"
         + module.getModuleCode()
         +module.getModuleName());
    try{
     this.mailSender.send(msg);
   }
   catch(MailException ex) {
     // simply log it and go on...
     System.err.println(ex.getMessage());   

}
return "/staff/checker/view_submission";
}
```

In the project servlet I added this:

```
     <beans:bean id="mailSender" 
   class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="mail.mycompany.com"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- this is a template message that we can pre-load with default state -->
<beans:bean id="templateMessage" 
   class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <beans:property name="from" value="customerservice@mycompany.com"/>
    <beans:property name="subject" value="Your order"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="moduleController" 
     class="com.**.**.controller.ModuleController">
    <beans:property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <beans:property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>
</beans:bean>
```

I also added two jars, JavaMail mail.jar and JAF activation.jar to the classpath. If this implementation is wrong and the cause of the exception please let me know.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a JAR dependency.  Figure out which JAR org.springframework.mail.MailException is in, and make sure it's either in your WAR's lib folder or provided by your app server somehow.

Comment: Thank you. I added the two jars to my project lib folder and refreshed the project followed by restarting the server and the exception was gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure you have the spring-context-support jar in your classpath.